# How to reset page in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, camera

I have the following code for a camera:

```
public sealed partial class Camera : Page
{
    double width, height;
    MediaCapture captureManager;
    bool flashOn = false;
    public Camera()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
    /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        captureManager = new MediaCapture();
        imagePreview.Source = null;
        capturePreview.Source = null;
        DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Landscape;
        width = Convert.ToInt32(Window.Current.Bounds.Width);
        height = Convert.ToInt32(Window.Current.Bounds.Height);
        capturePreview.Width = width;
        capturePreview.Height = height;
        imagePreview.Width = width;
        imagePreview.Height = height;
        Starter();

    }
    async private void Starter()
    {
        await captureManager.InitializeAsync();
        StartCapturePreview_Click();
    }

    async private void StartCapturePreview_Click()
    {
        capturePreview.Source = captureManager;
        await captureManager.StartPreviewAsync();
    }

    async private void StopCapturePreview_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await captureManager.StopPreviewAsync();
    }

    private async void focus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await captureManager.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.UnlockAsync();
                var focusSettings = new FocusSettings();
                focusSettings.AutoFocusRange = AutoFocusRange.Normal;
                focusSettings.Mode = FocusMode.Auto;
                focusSettings.WaitForFocus = true;
                focusSettings.DisableDriverFallback = false;
                captureManager.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.Configure(focusSettings);
                await captureManager.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.FocusAsync();
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }

    private async void flash_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (flashOn) flashOn = false;
        else flashOn = true;
        CapturePhoto.Content = flashOn.ToString();
        var foc = captureManager.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl;
        await foc.FocusAsync();
    }

    async private void CapturePhoto_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var flash = captureManager.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl;
        if (flashOn) flash.Enabled = true;
        await Task.Delay(500);
        ImageEncodingProperties imgFormat = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();

        // create storage file in local app storage 
        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
            "Photo.jpg",
            CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        // take photo 
        await captureManager.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imgFormat, file);

        // Get photo as a BitmapImage 
        BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.Path));

        // imagePreivew is a <Image> object defined in XAML 
        imagePreview.Source = bmpImage;
        flash.Enabled = false;
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    }
}
```

I'm trying to find a way to reset the page (for instance adding a button to retake the photo or returning to the same page later) but can't find a way...
I tried changing all of the initial construction of the objects in the OnNavigatedTo function but it still doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete the captureManager before you move a page and make the creation of it happen in OnNavigatedTo() and it will reset it.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 easiest ways to reset / reload a page that jump to my mind are:

Write a method that resets all fields and properties to their default states, and then call this method from your button press.

Or:

Launch the window that needs to be reset from another control and link the reset button to a method on the parent control to close and then re-open the page.

Hope that is helpful.

Comment: First way doesn't work. 
I didn't fully understand what you meant with the second solution